# How to run javascript with require node modules in local

Tags: javascript, jwt, node-modules

I am creating JWT for talkdesk , I am PHP Developer and talkdesk does not provide JWT creation in PHP , so I have decided to go with Javascript as per documentation I need two packages 'jsonwebtoken' and 'uuid', Which I have installed using NPM, within node_modules directory .

When I call them with require method , I am receiving following error

"Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined"

I am note sure how to run this code locally.

```
// Requires the 'jsonwebtoken' and 'uuid' packages to be installed
var jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
var uuid = require('uuid/v4');

var private_key = '<client_private_key>'
private_key = "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\n" + private_key + "\n-----END 
PRIVATE KEY-----"

var header = {
kid: '<client_key_id>'
}

var payload = {
iss: '<client_id>',
sub: '<client_id>',
aud: 'https://<account_name>.talkdeskid.com/oauth/token',
jti: uuid(),
exp: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 300,
iat: Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000)
}

token = jwt.sign(payload, private_key, {header: header, algorithm: 
'<client_key_algorith>'})
```

Any help would highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not running the script in browser?

Comment: if you're running it in browser, try replacing `require` statements with `import`, like `import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken'`

Comment: on the command line type: node <nameofyourscript>

Comment: hello @AdamKosmala , Can I run this file with node.js server ?

Comment: @arvindpundir why do you ask. I said it in my comment and also linked to another QA that explains how to do it. Did you try?

Comment: @jps  ohh,typo, my question was Can I run that js file without node server running